AWS DynamoDB BatchGetItemRequest select nested attributes from a list
I have the following structure in dynamodb:
{
  "id": 1,
  "prop1": "val1",
  "prop2": "val2"
  "list1": [
    {
      "listProp1": "listVal1",
      "listProp2": "listVal2",
    },
    {
      "listProp1": "listVal21",
      "listProp2": "listVal22",
    },
    {
      "listProp1": "listVal31",
      "listProp2": "listVal32",
    }
  ]
}

Then I need to select all elements where "id" is 1, 3, 10. And I need to select "prop1" from the main object as well as "listProp1" from the list of ""list1"" (all elements of the list). So I use BatchGetItemRequest.
var keyAttributes = new KeysAndAttributes
{
    Keys =
    {
        { "id", [1, 3, 10] },
    },
    AttributesToGet =
    {
        "prop1",
        "list1.listProp1",
    },
};

var req = new BatchGetItemRequest
{
    RequestItems =
    {
        { "mytable", keyAttributes },
    },
};

var res = await _dynamoDb.BatchGetItemAsync(req, ct)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

The response is asuccessfult, but "list1" is not returned because there is no such property as "list1.listProp1" in the main object, so I wonder: is there any way to select only specific nested properties or should "list1" be completely fetched from dynamoDb?

You're not searching for the correct term, "list1.listProp1" should be list1[0].listProp1.
You also have another issue, AttributesToGet is legacy, you should use ProjectionExpression instead, and ensure you provide the dot notation properly and not as a string.

I see, thank you for the reply, but just to be clear. Will "list1[0].listProp1" select "listProp1" only from the first element? Or from all elements. And if "list1" is empty will "list1[0].listProp1" throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception?

You cannot obtain it from all elements in a list, you have to specify the position in the list hence [0]

I see, then the only option is to select all properties of "list1".
